# How to post a message to Stocktwits through python script?

Tags: python, stocktwits

I have created an app, and have the token, the keys, and all that information from stocktwits.com. I want to know how i can integrate code into my python script where i am able to post a message to stocktwits via Python.

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python's request module, you could make a request like this:

```
import requests
payload={"access_token":"YOURACCESSTOKEN", "body":"YOURMESSAGE"}
requests.post("https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/messages/create.json", data=payload)
```

Be sure to look at [Stocktwit's auth docs](http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/authentication) so you can make sure that you have the right API keys.

Comment: hi Jake,

So i have the access_token from following the auth docs "Client side OAuth flow:" section. I entered the token in "YOURACESSTOKEN" and ran a simple python script to post a message "TEST". However it's not posting that message when i run the python script.

Comment: @PowerrJoe The only thing I can think of is to make sure that you're using the correct token. Otherwise you can look at the response from the server to see if it gave an error message.

Comment: I have the correct token, but does each new message need a new token to be published? I am not sure where i am going wrong. And what's the difference between client side OAuth and Server side OAuth

Comment: I don't think that each message should need a new one (their docs say that there's no need to refresh it). One other thing you could try is not using `json.dumps()` (i.e. do this: requests.post("https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/messages/create.json", data=payload)). If that doesn't work, I would look at the server response and trace it from there.